# i18n translation library is not working in some pages in nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I am using i18n library with NextJS to apply internationalization ot my web application. It is working perfectly for all pages except one /page/[id].js file. It is only working with default language there. However, I have another page /sorted/[id].js. And there there is no any problem.

It's my _app.js file:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
export default MyApp;
```

This i18n.json file:

```
{
    "locales": ["en", "ru", "uz"],
    "defaultLocale": "en",
    "pages": {
      "*": ["common"]
    }
}
```

This is a next.config.js file

```
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");

module.exports = nextTranslate();
```

Finally this is how I am using translation in my /page/[id].js file

```
import React from "react";
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";

const Post = (props) => {
  const { t, lang } = useTranslation("common");
  return(
    <p>{t("Recommendations for you")}</p>
  )
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: next-translate is not next-i18next... do you may want to remove the i18next tag